# Index was outside the bounds of the array vb2008

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2008

Im looking into an old application and every time i try to send a piece of information it comes up with "Index was outside the bounds of the array" - The following is the line it is coming from

```
If Curl(APIAddress & "/api.php", String.Format("&action=addticketreply&username={0}&password={1}&ticketid={2}&adminusername={0}&message={3}", APIUsername, ConvertStringToMD5(APIPassword), TicketID, txtMessage.EditValue())) = True Then
```

I was just wondering if someone could help point out what exactly is wrong so I could look into it and possible learn a bit more about it for future reference

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried isolating the parameters of Curl? Like send empty values for all but one parameter and check if it fails.

Comment: Hi there, It connects to an online ticketing database , Each time ive run it, it comes up with that error but yet still posts the ticket over to the database - All the array details are needed for it to access and store the ticket so there would be no physical way for it to store it if it was failing